# can't retrieve longblob audio file from database

Tags: php, mysql

i was inserting audio files to my database and i was retreiving them just fine then some files just won't be retrieved even tho i'm using the same code here's the code 
getAudio.php

```
    <?php
include 'conn.php';
// to connect with the database
  $id = $_GET['id'];
  // validation just to be safe

  $sql = "SELECT file FROM letters1 WHERE id=$id"; 
  // choose the column from the table where the id= the id of the audio file

  $result = mysql_query("$sql");
  //query the audio file

  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
  //Returns an associative array

  mysql_close($link);
  //closes the non-persistent connection to the MySQL

  header("Content-type: audio/mpeg"); 
  //audio/wav for wav files mpeg for mp3 files, we used mp3 cuz 
  //wav didn't work on IE so just to be sure

 echo $row['file'];
 //calls the audio file and returns it in the src attribute
?>
```

returnblobfile.php

```
<?php include 'php/conn.php'
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>new</title></head>
<body>
<audio controls>
<source src="php/getAudio.php?id=14" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

i'm using phpMyAdmin it stopped on id 14, 16, 19, 20 and they are not empty i kept on editing them. 
please help .. thanks in advance

Comment: you are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply assuming your query succeeded. never **EVER** assume success with a db operation. always assume failure, check for failure, and treat success as a pleasant surprise.

Answer (score 0):

SQL injection aside, you code seems ok. May be you reach some memory or storage limit:

- Guess 1: you are using fields of type blob but your file is bigger than that and was truncated when inserted into the table. Using a field type with more capacity could be a solution (mediumblob or longblob).
- Guess 2: the content of `file` field is too heavy for the php memory limit. You can try allowing more with something like this:

Using and .htaccess file:

```
    php_value memory_limit 128M
```

Or using ini_set at the top of your script:

```
    ini_set('memory_limit', '128M');
```

(32, 64, 128 or whatever number works for you)

*EDIT: oops... didn't pay attention, the title already says you are using longblob ^^*